# How do I close a program from the terminal

Tags: command-line, files, directory, kill

Suppose for example vlc media player is running and some directory is also opened in file browser. Now I want to close either the file browser or vlc.

One way can be to just click on the cross button on the top left hand corner, but how can I do this using terminal commands?

Comment: What do you mean by file or folder? you mean file manager?

Comment: I don't know what you mean but may be your referring to using the `kill command` in the terminal?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I kill a specific X window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/833303/how-can-i-kill-a-specific-x-window)

Answer (score 14):

Now every file is handled by another program say `gedit` and folders the same, so to kill [ the program handling that file or folder ] we can use two methods:

1. The program name with:

   ```
   pkill <name_of_program>
   ```
2. use of program `PID` (process id)

   - find the `PID` with `pgrep <name_of_program>`, then
   - kill it with `kill <PID>`

Information:

```
man pkill
man kill
```

**Note:** When closed this way any unsaved changes will be lost.

Comment: They want the same behavior as clicking "on the cross button on the top left hand corner", which isn't `-9`, since `-9` doesn't give the program the opportunity to close properly like clicking the "cross button".

Comment: @Chait.rex now assuming user has saved their files and kills the app would there be anything wrong in that?

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex It can be useful when for example program doesn't respond in the GUI and clicking the cross button doesn't close it.